# Can rewrites fallback if 404? Rewrite conflict issue

Tags: rewrite-rules, 404-error

I have pages and product categories on my site:

```
Pages:
--About
--Contact
Products:
--Category 1
----Subcategory 1
--Category 2
```

Ideally I want mysite.com/category-1/subcategory-1 to show the product category page and mysite.com/about to show a normal page. I have registered the taxonomy in the following way:

```
function products_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'product_categories',
        'product',
        array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'label' => 'Product Categories',
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'hierarchical' => true,
                'slug' => '/',
                'with_front' => false
            )
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'products_taxonomy');
```

Currently, the category URL is working, but the page URL eg mysite.com/about/ is 404ing.

I have installed the [Rewrite Analyzer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) plugin and I can see this is because Wordpress is only checking for a product category called "about", which it can't find, hence the 404. It is not checking subsequent rewrite rules. **Is there a way I can catch this 404 and get Wordpress to check the next rewrite rule instead of immediately showing a 404?** I'm a bit confused as to why this is not the default behaviour...

[image]

Comment: unfortunately that's not how it works. WordPress doesn't know it's a 404 until after it tries to query the database, which is a few steps after rewrite rules are parsed. It's not impossible, but you basically have to go looking in the database yourself ro resolve the conflict. This is why unique slugs prefix custom content types.

Comment: Definitely how it should work.